# Calcular média, mediana, variância e desvio padrão

Tags: tidyverse, k-means

Eu preciso calcular média, mediana, desvio padrão e variância da seguinte base de dados:

```
install.packages("devtools")
# devtools::install_github("tbrugz/ribge")
library(ribge)
pop2020 <- populacao_municipios(2020)
```

Segue a pergunta:
Para a variável "populacao", calcule: (i) a média,
(ii) a mediana,
(iii) o desvio padrão e
(iv) a variância.

Apresente os resultados em uma tabela (dica: usar a função ”kable” do pacote ”knitr”).
Coloque um titulo na sua tabela.

Eu fiz da seguinte forma:

```
install.packages("knitr")
library(knitr)

df <- pop2020 %>%
  summarise(pop_media = mean(populacao),
            pop_mediana = mean(populacao),
            pop_desvio_padrao = sd(populacao),
            pop_variancia = var(populacao)) %>%
```

No console aparece a seguinte mensagem: Error: unexpected assignment in " <-"

Onde estou errando?